# React Js Looping over a parent array for login authorisation

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

Right so I have passed an array down to the child from the parent and I will include all code below

so what I am trying to do is loop over my array and check that my user input matches one of the objects in the array if it does continue with the code if not give an error prompt

my code for the parent is

```
...
state = {
    AuthResults: [
        {
            id: 1,
            username: "Andy",
            password: "Andy"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            username: "Dan",
            password: "Dan"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            username: "Naheem",
            password: "Naheem"
        }
    ],
}
...
<LoginBar AuthRes={this.state.AuthRes}/>
...
```

My Code for the child is

```
CheckLoginAuth(){
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    Object.keys(this.state.AuthRes).map(function(key){
        console.log(AuthRes[key]);
    })

}
...
<TextField floatingLabelText="Username" name="Username" onChange={this.handleUsername} value={this.state.Username} type="text" />
<TextField floatingLabelText="Password" name="Password" onChange={this.handlePassword} value={this.state.Password} type="text" />
<RaisedButton label="Login" secondary={true} onClick={() => this.onRealLoginClick()} /><span>&nbsp;</span>
...
```

it pulls the object in fine as it prints it but i cant seem to do the loop and auth.

EDIT: Right so i got no errors now by changing my CheckLoginAuth function to this

```
CheckLoginAuth(){
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    this.props.AuthRes.map(function(Res){
        console.log(Res.id);
        console.log(Res.username);
        console.log(Res.password);
    })
}
```

how do i loop through the ids in Res and compare them to the user inputs

Comment: I don't see where you're looping through AuthRes...

Comment: Because i need to check the users input from the TextField to see if the users inputs match one of the ids' username and password as its for a login file (obviously the data will eventually go into my api but i dont know c# so i have to wait for one of the other dev so im trying to work it out now

Comment: @JonB Im not looping through it because everything ive tried hasnt work im asking how to do it. I will be doing it in the CheckLoginAuth function

Comment: If you post what isn't working, you're much more likely to get an answer showing you how to make it work.

Comment: @JonB I added what ive tried. thats only the loop i have no clue for the checking part. that gives me an error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: `Object.keys(this.state.AuthRes)`: Take out the `Object.keys` part - just map `this.state.AuthRes` and see if that gets you closer to where you want to be. `Object.keys` in this case will return the members of the array object, not its elements.

Comment: @JonB that give me Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Ah - you probably want `this.props.AuthRes`, since you're passing that to the child as a property.

Comment: @JonB this.props.AuthRes also gives me cannot read property of map

Comment: @andywilson you have passed 'this.state.AuthRes' and then in state you have mentioned as 'AuthResults' . Is it just a typo or this is what it is?

Comment: @Upasana thats because i passed AuthResults through from the parent into the prop AuthRes as to not confuse myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing

```
CheckLoginAuth() {
    console.log("gets to check login auth");
    console.log(this.state.AuthRes);
    console.log("Username=" + this.state.Username);
    console.log("Password=" + this.state.Password);
    var self = this;
    this.props.AuthRes.map(function (Res) {
        console.log("ID=" + Res.id);
        console.log("Username=" + Res.username);
        console.log("Password=" + Res.password);
        self.LoginAuth(Res);
    });
}
```

instead of what i wrote above